# Receiving rtp packets and writing them into binary file

Tags: c

I am receiving rtp packets from a server that I have to write them into a .mp3 file and I have a few questions on how to complete this task. The last packet I am receiving contains an "END" string.
My code is the following:

```
int size = 524;
char rtp[size];

FILE *f;
f=fopen("music.mp3","wb");


while(strcmp((char *)rtp, "END")){
    recvfromserver(socket,rtp,sizeof(rtp));
    fwrite(rtp, sizeof(rtp), 1,  f);
    }

fclose(f);
```

My questions are the following:

Is char the correct type for this type of packet? I have to write the file in binary so I do not know if I am doing it right.

How do I write into the file without writing the header of the rap packet? This header is 12B and I should remove it before doing fwrite(), but I do not know if I have to use char or int.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `char*` is the right data type for your need. In fact I would be more inclined to use `unsigned char*`

I have done the following modification to your code:-

- Initialized the rtp buffer - Think of a case the stack memory where rtp is defined contains `"END\0XXX"` ? Your write loop will never execute. Always a good practice to initialize variables form stack
- Since you are saying you don't need to write the first 12 bytes from rtp, I have advanced the byte pointer by 12 in `fwrite`
- Adjusted the 2nd param of `fwrite` by 12 bytes to ensure you are not writing form beyond 524 bytes of `rtp`
- You might have to think about what you get from `recvfromserver` Is that a null terminated character array?

Modified code:-

```
int size = 524;
char rtp[size] = {0}; //Initialized rtp

FILE *f;
f=fopen("music.mp3","wb");

while(strcmp((char *)rtp, "END")){
    recvfromserver(socket,rtp,sizeof(rtp));
    fwrite(rtp+12, sizeof(rtp)-12, 1, f); //adjusted for 12 bytes of header
    }

fclose(f);
```

Comment: that is perfect exactly what I was missing! thanks so much!

Comment: Use `memcmp` instead of `strcmp`!